# Using Android for calling Open Bank Project with OAuth1

Tags: java, android, oauth, deep-linking, open-banking

I try to using the open bank project (OBP) in my android app. I want to list banks and the user can choose one or more of them to own list.

For this I clone the example app by OBP: https://github.com/OpenBankProject/Hello-OBP-OAuth1.0a-Android

Here my steps:

1. Register on OBP-Page and register App for Keys:  https://apisandbox.openbankproject.com/consumer-registration

[image]
[image]

1. Clone example app https://github.com/OpenBankProject/Hello-OBP-OAuth1.0a-Android
2. Open in Android Studio.
3. Open OBPRestClient.java and change OBP_AUTH_KEY and OBP_SECRET_KEY by "Consumer Key" and "Consumer Secret". Change BASE_URL to "https://apisandbox.openbankproject.com".
4. Open OAuthActivity.java and remove if (1 == 1)
           throw new RuntimeException("Setup required! See OAuthActivity.java");
5. Open in res/values/strings and change customAppProtocol value to "intent".
6. Open AndroidManifest and set intent filter for 
   [image]
7. If I start the app a browser started and i must login to OBP-API. I do this and get a message by OBP.
   [image]
8. If I click on "here" the app dont start. I think my redirect url is wrong :(

**what is the solution for this problem?**

Comment: "here" has which url ? can you please share that here.

Comment: how i can see this on my android device? in logcat?

Comment: check in browser first

Answer (score 0):

You need set same app_name of your app in  name="customAppProtocol">app_name¨  and create new register in open bank project with redirectURL = app_name:/ 
That work for me.